# "POST /user/create/ HTTP/1.1" 500 82190

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am having a problem setting up authentication in django rest. Everytime I try to create a user using a post request to this url **http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/create/** I get this error: **AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`
[09/Apr/2021 14:41:43] "POST /user/create/ HTTP/1.1" 500 82190**. I have tried may solutions here with no success.

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status, permissions
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView 


from .serializers import CustomUserSerializer, MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
    
class CustomUserCreate(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, format = 'json'):
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(data= request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                json = serializer.data
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length = 8, write_only= True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

        def create(self, validated_data):
            password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
            instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
            
            if password is not None:
                instance.set_password(password)
            instance.save()
            return instance
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework_simplejwt import views as jwt_views
from .views import ObtainTokenPairWithColorView, CustomUserCreate, HelloWorld

urlpatterns = [
    path('user/create/', CustomUserCreate.as_view(), name="create_user"),
]
```

Comment: You did not return anything if `serializer.is_valid()` is `False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view does not return anything when `serializer.is_valid()` returns `False`. In that case you need to produce a response as well. Likely this is due to bad indentation:

```
class CustomUserCreate(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, format = 'json'):
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(data= request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                json = serializer.data
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        # outside the body of the if clause
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```